# In flash builder, how do I change the root so relative paths start from a different folder?

Tags: url, flash-builder, root

I already have a project created in flash builder that is uploaded to a server and running just fine.  The problem is when I want to test locally, nothing works because all my links and resources are set to relative URL's and not a full IP address and path.

When I try to run flash builder from my local copy, I can't access all these resources because flash is trying to look at C:\backend\resources rather than C:\Users\User\Documents\Java Workspace\backend\resources

How do I change flash builder's root to be in the proper location?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just wound up changing my setup to hit my local urls and simply don't commit the file.  Kind of a lame answer, but it works.